# Unable to obtain Proper Stack Trace after running the dump file with WinDbg

Tags: windbg, w3wp, debugdiag

We are having exception thrown on `Production` that causes the `w3wp process` to crash. To figure out the faulted code, we configured the `Debug Diag` that is creating dump file when `exception` occur. Then we are trying to run the dump file with `WinDbg` to obtain the `Stack Trace` to figure out the faulted code but this is what we are experiencing after opening the dump file and running the required `commands`.

[image]

As you can see in the image above, it's not giving the `stack trace` after running the `commands`, I'm not sure what I'm missing

**UPDATE**

After running a `command` twice as suggested in the `comments`, I'm able to get the `stack trace`. But seems like there is no faulted code pointed out in the `stack` instead there is a long list of underlying `framework` in the `stack`. Below is the `snapshot` for the start of `stack`. Not sure how to identify the error. Any suggestion or I may need to open separate `Question` for this?

[image]

Comment: Just run the command again. This is a known issue in dbgeng.dll and has been worked around in CoreCLR SOS. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/46723fca-8d7c-4d61-b447-14e3bef01df8/windbg-access-violation-exception-0xc0000005-when-running-the-clrstack-command

Comment: @Dono I always did `.symfix;.reload;!analyze -v` and then run the command again and now you're telling me I can just repeat it? This will save some time

Comment: @Thomas The issue does not always reproduce, but I experience this issue on a daily basis on multiple machines. Repeating the command always works for me. Another workaround is to load SOS by giving the extension: .loadby sos.dll clr (or mscorwks). See the link above for details. A workaround was added in CoreCLR to avoid secondary initialization. The real fix should be done in dbgeng.dll, though.

Comment: @Dono Thanks, that works. I updated my question, can you please check and suggest?

Comment: You've got a `stack overflow` exception, and you can see some of the repeating frames in the screen capture. You probably want to scan down further in the stack trace to see where it started to spiral out of control.

Comment: @AmmarKhan You only need to load SOS once. If the first command fails, such as !sos.clrstack in this case, just re-run the same command (!sos.clrstack) again. You can verify that it is only loaded once with the .chain command. Use .unload to fix if necessary. The first screen capture indicates that you have a stack overflow. It probably won't add anything new, but try !sos.pe to verify the last exception details. Check for repeating (looping) frames in the stack trace.

Comment: @Dono Thanks for keep helping me trace the faulted coded. I ran the `!sos.pe` and get the following `exception` detail `The controller for path '/admin/server-status' was not found or does not implement IController.` which is indeed not the correct url. But my application already configured to handle wrong url's by redirecting to friendly `404` error screen. But seems like that is not seems to be working for `admin` area, not sure why.

Comment: @Dono Also, about repeating frames in the stack trace, this is what is keep repeating till end of trace `ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute()`. Any thoughts?